# Http status not triggering on try and catch javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I have function to post JSON to an API end point which is working fine. This is my code.

```
function sendValuesPageLoad(){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        try {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {}
        } catch (ex) {
            alert('Error parsing response.');
        }
     }
     try {
        xhr.open("POST", "test.html?"+encodedString, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send();
     } catch (ex) {
        xhr.open("POST", "error.html?"+encodedString, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send();
     }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to perform further action if the xhr.status is not equal to 200.

But the catch is not being triggered.

Can anyone please help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `throw` if status is not `200`.

Comment: why do you the expect it to be triggered? there can be no exception

Comment: @randomSoul didn t understand you. Can you edit my code pls as an exampld?

Comment: with your current code there is no exception, so it will not execute your `catch` block. If you want to execute your `catch` block if status is not `200`. You can add if statement which check's if status is not 200 and then use throw statement inside it, so your `catch` block gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function sendValuesPageLoad(){
   var encodedString = "value=2";

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   console.log('UNSENT: ', xhr.status);

   xhr.open("POST", "test.html?" + encodedString, true);
   console.log('OPENED: ', xhr.status);
   
   xhr.onprogress = function () {
     console.log('LOADING: ', xhr.status);
   };
   
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   
   xhr.onload = function () {
     console.log('DONE: ', xhr.status);
     
     if(xhr.status === 200){
        alert("Status code is 200");
        
     }else{
         alert("Status code is not 200, but " + xhr.status);
     
        xhr.open("POST", "error.html?"+encodedString, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send();
     }
   };
   
   xhr.send();  
}

sendValuesPageLoad();
```

Comment: I have modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

`XMLHttpRequest` comes with its own error handler `onerror`. Updating your example

```
function sendValuesPageLoad(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
       if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // successful
       } else {
          // fails
          throw new Error('Failed with status: ' + xhr.statusText);
       }
    }
    xhr.onerror = function () {
       throw new Error('There is a problem');
    }
    xhr.open("POST", "test.html?"+encodedString, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send();
}
```

You can improve this by wrapping it in a `Promise` and catching any error

```
function sendValuesPageLoad(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
       if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // successful
          resolve(xhr.response);
       } else {
          // fails
          reject(xhr.statusText);
       }
    }
    xhr.onerror = function () {
       reject(Error("Network Error"));
    }
    xhr.open("POST", "test.html?"+encodedString, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send();
  }
}

// use case
sendValuesPageLoad().then(function(response) { 
   // use your response here
}).catch(function(error) {
   // handle your error
});
```